# What's the good way to convert a big list of integers into a list of floats between 0-1?

Tags: python

```
import random
numbers = []
for i in range(1000000):
    numbers.append(random.randrange(1,1000000))

sum = 0
for n in numbers:
    sum += n

ratios = []
for n in numbers:
    ratios.append(round(n/sum, 8))

print(ratios[:30])
```

I want to get a list of floats that can represent the percentage of each integer in the whole list. My actual data are not random, but the example data shows the idea. The resulting ratios are very small for each.

Is there a better way to convert integer list into a list of percentage floats?

Comment: "*The resulting ratios are very small for each.*" Mathematically speaking, why would you expect anything else? Individual components of a 1,000,000 digit set will of course be "*small*" pieces of the larger sum.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem using loop is not efficient. I suggest you to use `numpy` library. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.randint(1,1000000, size=1000000) # generate random numpy array of int
array = array.astype(np.float)/1000000 # casting integer to float between 0 and 1
```

In this way you can efficiently generate a large set of random numbers and cast them to different datatypes. Under the hood numpy provided with low level programming to make this faster and efficient in Python.

Answer (score 0):

More pythonic:

```
>>> numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> s = sum(numbers)
>>> s
45
>>> ratios = [ x/s for x in numbers]
>>> ratios
[0.022222222222222223, 0.044444444444444446, 0.06666666666666667, 0.08888888888888889, 0.1111111111111111, 0.13333333333333333, 0.15555555555555556, 0.17777777777777778, 0.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose "better" is a tad subjective... Is it "better" to make the code a bit less readable but more performant? Up to what point? Or... maybe it'd be "better" making it slower but less memory intensive?

Bikeshedding or... erm... philosophical digressions from a bored old guy aside : I've always found that the built in tools provided by Python itself tend to provide pretty good results.

In your code, a couple of things that come to mind are:

1. Don't add the numbers yourself. Use the built-in [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) for that
2. More importantly, use the built in [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply your ratio function to your `numbers` iterable

Something like:

```py
import random
numbers = []
for i in range(1000000):
    numbers.append(random.randrange(1,1000000))

total = sum(numbers)
ratios = list(map(lambda n: round(n/total, 8), numbers))
print(ratios[:30])
```

Depending on the usage, you could even keep `ratios` as the iterator that `map` returns (not casting it to `list`)

A quick, dirty and completely unreliable time measurement with `datetime.now()` shows that your method takes roughly 1 second in my computer while using `sum` and `map` takes about half a second.

```py
# ---- Original
import random
from datetime import datetime
numbers = []
for i in range(1000000):
    numbers.append(random.randrange(1,1000000))

total = 0
for n in numbers:
    total += n

start = datetime.now()
ratios = []
for n in numbers:
    ratios.append(round(n/total, 8))

print(f"Cost {datetime.now() - start}")
print(ratios[:30])

# ---- Compacted
import random
from datetime import datetime
numbers = []
for i in range(1000000):
    numbers.append(random.randrange(1,1000000))

total = sum(numbers)
start = datetime.now()
ratios = list(map(lambda n: round(n/total, 8), numbers))
print(f"Cost {datetime.now() - start}")
print(ratios[:30])
```